# can i make a function return multiple values in a list?

Tags: python, list, pygame

Here is my circle class:

```
class circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(10, SW-10)
        self.y = random.randint(10, SH-10)
        self.radius = random.randint(5, 50)
        self.color =  (random.randint(1, 255),random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255))

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(d, (self.color), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    def move(self):
        self.x = X
        self.y = Y
```

From this circle class, i have made one user circle by doing `user = circle()` and 20 random circles by doing

```
circles = list()
for i in range(20):
   circles.append(circle())`
```

Here is my cillision detection:

```
def circle_collision(cir1, cir2):
    a = abs(cir2.x - cir1.x)**2
    b = abs(cir2.y - cir1.y)**2
    distance = math.sqrt((a) + (b))
    if  distance < cir1.radius + cir2.radius:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My problem is i cant pass the list `circles` as one of my arguments for collision detection but i also want the program to detect when the `user = circle()` cirlce collides with any of the other random circles. 
Initially, i tried doing this to solve my problem:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(len(circles)):
        result = circles[i]
    return result
```

I hoped for this to return every item in the list so i could call collision detection as follows inside the `while True` loop as:

```
collided = circle_collision(user, foo())
```

But the `foo` function returns only one value so theers only one circle the collision detection can detect. What can i do to make the `collision_detection` check every single circle? Is there a way to make a function return multiple values? or will i have to change my logic entirely? Thanks for helping.

Here is my entire program for reference.

```
import pygame, math, os, random

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"]="1"
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display
win.set_caption("A lot a circles")
SW = 1200
SH = 600
d = win.set_mode((SW, SH))
pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

def write(size, text, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Aeiral", size)
    text = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    d.blit(text, (x, y))

def circle_collision(cir1, cir2):
    a = abs(cir2.x - cir1.x)**2
    b = abs(cir2.y - cir1.y)**2
    distance = math.sqrt((a) + (b))
    if  distance < cir1.radius + cir2.radius:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(10, SW-10)
        self.y = random.randint(10, SH-10)
        self.radius = random.randint(5, 50)
        self.color =  (random.randint(1, 255),random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255))

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(d, (self.color), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    def move(self):
        self.x = X
        self.y = Y

user = circle()

def foo():
    for i in range(len(circles)):
        result = circles[i]
    return result

circles = list()
for i in range(20):
   circles.append(circle())

mainloop = True
while mainloop:
    X, Y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    d.fill((98, 98, 98))
    for i in circles:
        i.draw()
    user.draw()
    user.move()
    write(user.radius, "USER", user.x - user.radius + 2, user.y - 7)
    collided = circle_collision(user, foo())
    if collided == True:
        user.color = (255, 0, 0)
    if collided == False:
        user.color = (255, 255, 255)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainloop = False

    win.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another function which evaluates if a circle collides with an circle of a list and creates a new list with the colliding circles:

```py
def circles_collision(cir1, cirlist):
    collidlist = []
    for cir2 in cirlist:
        if circle_collision(cir1, cir2):
            collidlist.append(cir2)
    return collidlist
```

Or even shorter:

```py
def circles_collision(cir1, cirlist):
    return [cir2 for cir2 in cirlist if circle_collision(cir1, cir2)]
```

Test if `collidelist` has [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) element:

```py
collidelist = circles_collision(user, circles)
if any(collidelist):
    user.color = (255, 0, 0)
else:
    user.color = (255, 255, 255)
```

---

If you just want to evaluate if any circle collides, then you don't need a list and a separate function at all:

```py
if any(circle_collision(user, circle) for circle in circles):  
    user.color = (255, 0, 0)
else:
    user.color = (255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: you don't need a whole new function for that -- `(circle_collision(user, circle) for circle in circles)` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return a list. Also, there's no need to do `for i in range(len(circles))`; you can more easily write `for circle in circles`. Also, there's no reason in this case to loop over the `circles` list just to return a copy of that list. And be sure you're not resetting the color for every circle -- you just want to set the color if any collisions happened, where if you set it every time through the loop you'd end up only using the collision from the last one. Try:

```
collisions = (circle_collision(user, circle) for circle in circles)
if any(collisions):
    user.color = (255, 0, 0)
else:
    user.color = (255, 255, 255)
```